# Arduino(Ruby client) to Http server (Rails Application) direct communication using publish-subscribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, arduino, rabbitmq

Is it possible to implement REST client ( not browser but ruby client works on arduino device ) to access resource if resource is available via publish subscribe strategy ? (for example: http server(rails application) informed client that resource is now available you can receive/download)

I want to build application for **"communication directly between ruby client in arduino board to http server"**. **I don't want to use middle layer like Rabbitmq, zeromq.** **If it is possible what can be the possible steps to follow ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use HTTP for pub/sub.

If you don't want to use message queue(anyMQ), try using plain TCP/UDP sockets.

XMPP is not the best choice, it gives too much overhead.